# Pgsql return from second table even if no record exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have columns in the first table

**permission_id -  permission**

and columns second table

**user_id -  permission_id -- is_allowed**

Now The below query is working fine when row exists for user_id

```
select 
                f.permission,
                coalesce(s.is_allowed,false) as is_allowed
                
            from table1 f
        left join table2 s on f.permission_id = s.permission_id
            where s.user_id = 282
```

But it returns null when there are no rows in the second table for the user

What I need, it should return all rows from the first table and is_allowed as it exists in the second table, if not exists it should return false.

I tried where `s.is_allowed is null` but the output is not correct

> first table is master table of permissions, and second table has users
> with permission allowed, so I need to show all the permissions and
> then against it if allowed true else false, by default it should be
> false if there is no entry for users in second table

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that should be

```
from table2 s left join table1 f on f.permission_id = s.permission_id
```

i.e. just the opposite of what you have because `table2` will contain data for `user_id = 282`, but its `permission_id` column will be *empty* (`NULL`) and there's no value you could join with table of all permissions.

Alternatively, use `right` join:

```
from table1 f right join table2 s on f.permission_id = s.permission_id
```

---

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

PERMISSION_ID PERMISSION
------------- ------------
            1 permission 1
            2 permission 2

SQL> select * From table2;

   USER_ID PERMISSION_ID IS_A
---------- ------------- ----
       100             1 true
       282
```

If everything is OK (permission_id exists for user 100):

```
SQL> select s.user_id,
  2         f.permission,
  3         coalesce(s.is_allowed, 'false') as is_allowed
  4  from table2 s left join table1 f on f.permission_id = s.permission_id
  5  where s.user_id = 100;

   USER_ID PERMISSION   IS_AL
---------- ------------ -----
       100 permission 1 true
```

Permission ID is NULL for user 282:

```
SQL> select s.user_id,
  2         f.permission,
  3         coalesce(s.is_allowed, 'false') as is_allowed
  4  from table2 s left join table1 f on f.permission_id = s.permission_id
  5  where s.user_id = 282;

   USER_ID PERMISSION   IS_AL
---------- ------------ -----
       282              false

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If it is the other way round (as you commented), then:

This is your "original" query which doesn't return anything if user 282 is in `where` clause; that's expected because it filters rows out:

```
SQL> select s.user_id,
  2         f.permission,
  3         coalesce(s.is_allowed, 'false') as is_allowed
  4  from table1 f left join table2 s on f.permission_id = s.permission_id
  5  where s.user_id = 282;

no rows selected
```

What happens if you remove that condition entirely? Query then returns row for user 100 (because there's a join between tables through permission ID), and leaves another one without user ID because there's no join for that user:

```
SQL> select s.user_id,
  2         f.permission,
  3         coalesce(s.is_allowed, 'false') as is_allowed
  4  from table1 f left join table2 s on f.permission_id = s.permission_id;

   USER_ID PERMISSION   IS_AL
---------- ------------ -----
       100 permission 1 true
           permission 2 false
```

Or, if you want to apply filter on user 282, don't use it in `where` clause, but *expand* join condition; that result is, though different because it says that user 282 doesn't have neither permission:

```
SQL> select s.user_id,
  2         f.permission,
  3         coalesce(s.is_allowed, 'false') as is_allowed
  4  from table1 f left join table2 s on f.permission_id = s.permission_id and s.user_id = 282;

   USER_ID PERMISSION   IS_AL
---------- ------------ -----
           permission 1 false
           permission 2 false
```

Comment: NO, first table is master table of permissions, and second table has users with permission allowed, so I need to show all the permissions and then against it if allowed true else false, by default it should be false if there is no entry for users in second table

Comment: Have a look at edited info, please.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the root cause, in second table I have duplicate permission id that was causing my confusion with results

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you made it work.